# Sqoop Error: --table or --query is required for import

Tags: oracle, sqoop

I am getting the command not found errors while using the following sqoop command(oracle query).
I used another sqoop command to connect to another DB with a different jdbc connection string, it connected and fetched the data without error.
Not sure what the problem is here, can someone help fixing this error? Thanks in advance.

```
`sqoop import 
 --connectjdc:oracle:thin:@//(connection string)
 --query 
"Select sys, 
case when (substring(gid,3,3))="_A_" or gid="NJ_Parsipanny") then "core"
when
else "misc" end "org",
aid, aname,
b.workid as "waddress",
f.ai,
a.ag,
b.jobd,
b.jobk,
e.emstatus,
b.jobfunc,
b.superid,
c.fname+" "+c.lname as "S_Name",
FROM ad.db.tbl_a a
left join common.db.b b
on a.tid=b.sbid
left join common.db.c c
on b.sid=c.sbid
left join common.db.d d
on c.sid=d.sbid
left join common.db.e e
on d.sid=e.sbid
left join ad.db.tbl_f f
on a.AG=f.AG 
WHERE RIGHT(a.AG,1) IN ("E","T")
AND \$CONDITIONS"
--num-mappers 1
--target-dir /abc/46780
--fields-terminated-by ","
--user-name xyz
--password-file hdfs:///abc/46780/p/pswd.txt`
```

Errors: command not found.
--table or --query is required for import
line 26:--query:  command not found
line 44:--num-mappers: command not found
line 45:--target-dir: command not found
line 46:--fields-terminated-by: command not found
line 47:--username:command not found
line 48:--password-file: command not found

Comment: --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//(connection string)*

Answer (score 0):

Looks like shell script is giving you the error not `sqoop`.

When you have single command but divided into multiple line you need to add backslash `\` in each line ending.

```sh
sqoop import \
 --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//(connection string) \
 --query \
'Select sys,
case when (substring(gid,3,3))="_A_" or gid="NJ_Parsipanny") then "core"
when
else "misc" end "org",
aid, aname,
b.workid as "waddress",
f.ai,
a.ag,
b.jobd,
b.jobk,
e.emstatus,
b.jobfunc,
b.superid,
c.fname+" "+c.lname as "S_Name",
FROM ad.db.tbl_a a
left join common.db.b b
on a.tid=b.sbid
left join common.db.c c
on b.sid=c.sbid
left join common.db.d d
on c.sid=d.sbid
left join common.db.e e
on d.sid=e.sbid
left join ad.db.tbl_f f
on a.AG=f.AG 
WHERE RIGHT(a.AG,1) IN ("E","T")
AND $CONDITIONS' \
--num-mappers 1 \
--target-dir /abc/46780 \
--fields-terminated-by "," \
--user-name xyz \
--password-file hdfs:///abc/46780/p/pswd.txt
```

**Note:** Don’t need to add `\` inside quotes.
**Changes:**

1. I have changed double quotes to single quotes as you have double quotes inside your SQL query.
2. Remove `\` before `$CONDITIONS` as using single quotes does need $ to escape. It by default does.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the you are running the sqoop command from the `linux shell command line`.

I would rewrite the sqoop command as follow.

First, I would test the query through the Oracle console to see if the query is working fine.

Second, to the end of each line you should put the slash `\`

Third, you should put strings literals into the query between single quotes `'string literal'` instead of double quotes.

```sh
sqoop import \
--connectjdc:oracle:thin:@//(connection string) \
--query  "Select sys, 
case when (substring(gid,3,3))='_A_' or gid='NJ_Parsipanny') then 'core'
when
else 'misc' end 'org',
aid, aname,
b.workid as waddress,
f.ai,
a.ag,
b.jobd,
b.jobk,
e.emstatus,
b.jobfunc,
b.superid,
c.fname+' '+c.lname as S_Name,
FROM ad.db.tbl_a a
left join common.db.b b
on a.tid=b.sbid
left join common.db.c c
on b.sid=c.sbid
left join common.db.d d
on c.sid=d.sbid
left join common.db.e e
on d.sid=e.sbid
left join ad.db.tbl_f f
on a.AG=f.AG 
WHERE RIGHT(a.AG,1) IN ('E','T')
AND \$CONDITIONS" \
--num-mappers 1 \
--target-dir /abc/46780 \
--fields-terminated-by "," \
--username xyz \
--password-file hdfs:///abc/46780/p/pswd.txt
```